# can not access melpa packages- hung up at Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80

Tags: package, linux

I am trying to access the melpa packages but when typing:

```
package-refresh-contents
```

emacs gets hung up at: "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80"

I am completely new to emacs and fairly new to Linux and I have been stuck on this for a few hours.

I found this question on stackoverflow below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085937/package-refresh-contents-hangs-at-contacting-host-elpa-gnu-org80

and added:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

but it did not help.

I also tried switching https to http but that did not help either.

Can someone please help? Any suggestions or references would be much appreciated. Below is a screen shot of my code.

[image]

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/q/47686465/850781

Comment: Screenshots of code are almost never useful. Please copy and paste the code into the question, and remove the image.

Comment: Please do not post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one; delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a proxy to reach the package archive? Can you `ping elpa.gnu.org` from the command line?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that doesn't let you contact that host? Can you contact that host outside Emacs? Probably is not an Emacs problem if you can't.

Comment: If you need to tell Emacs about your proxy, see `M-x customize-option RET url-proxy-services RET`. You may need to `M-x load-library RET url RET` first. If you already have environment variables like `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` set when Emacs starts, then Emacs ought to be picking those up automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some alternatives for you in case you cannot access the official sites.

First:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu"   . "http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/elpa/gnu/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/elpa/melpa/")))
```

Second:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu"   . "http://elpa.emacs-china.org/gnu/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://elpa.emacs-china.org/melpa/")))
```

choose one to replace your settings listed above.

You can try to open the sites in your browser to check which sites you can access.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to overcome this problem although I tried the solutions suggested here and there.

I ended up by installing emacs25 and this problem did not occur.